# Trying to understand how each cell displays new information within my array? Swift and IOS

Tags: ios, swift

this is part of my code.

```
var taskArray:[taskModel] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let task1 = taskModel (first: "Hello", second: "World")
    let task2 = taskModel (first: "Hello", second: "again")
    let task3 = taskModel (first: "ok", second: "we get it")
    let task4 = taskModel (first: "alright", second: "we get it, you ass")
    let task5 = taskModel (first: "just...", second: "Get the fruit out")

    taskArray = [task1, task2, task3, task4, task5]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    println(indexPath.row)

    let task = taskArray[indexPath.row]

    var cell: TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TaskCell

    cell.taskLabel.text = task.first
    cell.labelLabel.text = task.second
```

I understand the the purpose of the datasource and delegate functions, but how does "let task = taskArray[indexPath.row]" display new information within each cell?
I assume one task is assigned to one cell, how does that play out in my code? as in where?

I was hoping someone could explain the logic.

Comment: The cell is reused because UI wise they are all the same with the exception of the data. Each time it is reused it passes an Int. This Int represents the cell row, which coincidentally matches the index of your array. When you pass an index to your array, it returns the string at that index…which you are assigning to the cell at that row.

Comment: `let task = taskArray[indexPath.row]` gets a task object out of your array. The last two lines update the labels in the cell with the text from the task object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has something called the **Parallel Data Structure**. Although this term is not used or said widely, there are many people understanding this principle though.

Essentially, it's talking about the *index* is matching with two different containers(**UITableViewCells** and your **data**). The way they can match with each other is because of the index. They are referencing to the same box(**cell** and **element** in an array). Thats' also the reason why you need to specify the number of elements the data source has. Because another container(**UITableView**) needs to know the number of cells.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function/method "**tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath**" receives 2 arguments from your view controller to be able to define what the cell will be filled with. In there you have one argument which is called "**indexPath**".

If you look how **indexPath** is build, you'll notice it has a "**section**" property and a "**row**" property. It's actually the address of the cell in the table.

When you poll your array with `taskArray[indexPath.row]`, you poll the array at the *index position* equal to the row of the cell in it's **indexPath** property.